# Angular 4.3.4 breaks mdInput and md-input-container

Tags: angular, angular-material2

My team at work recently went to Angular 4.3.3 from 4.3.0.  After these changes, mdInput and md-input-container no longer function correctly.  Before you could click into the input field and the animation would work as shown on material.angular.io/components/input.

Has anyone else run into this issue and if so, what steps did you take to resolve them?  May need to go back to 4.3.0.

```
package.json -

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^8.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is configuration for angular-material? How have you added it to your project?

Comment: I am at 4.3.2 and did not have any issues. Can you add the `@angular/...` dependencies & devDependencies from your `package.json` in the question description?

Comment: @micronyks - I've linked the indigo-pink theme to my index.html.  Everything was fine and dandy until we went to 4.3.4.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that I found an answer to the question.  On my index.html I was linking to this:

```
  <link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/material2-builds/master/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, when I removed that from the index.html and added this to styles.scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

it worked just fine and I didn't have the issues like before.