# mdInput has no style attached to it

Tags: angular, angular-material2

So I've this angular app and I want to add a mdInput textarea, but when I add it, it just deletes the textarea border and nothing else (underline or placeholder etc. animations none of them exist)

I'm using angular-material 2.0.0.beta-08 version.
It does not throw any error in console. And the other material components like md-select has no problem.

This is html code

```
<form class="example">

<md-input-container class="full-width">
    <textarea mdInput mdTextareaAutosize minRows="6" placeholder="Write a comment" formControlName="commentContent"></textarea>
</md-input-container>
```

And this is the relevant part of App Module

```
    imports: [
        MomentModule,
        MdInputModule,MdButtonModule,
 MdDialogModule, MdGridListModule,
 MdCheckboxModule, MdSelectModule,
 MdOptionModule, MdIconModule,
 MdProgressSpinnerModule, MdTooltipModule,
        FormsModule,
        ...
```

This is generated HTML

```
<md-input-container _ngcontent-c28="" class="full-width mat-input-container" ng-reflect-class-base="full-width">
<div class="mat-input-wrapper">
    <div class="mat-input-flex">
        <!----><div class="mat-input-infix">
            <textarea _ngcontent-c28="" class="mat-input-element" formcontrolname="commentContent" mdinput="" mdtextareaautosize="" minrows="6" placeholder="Write a comment" rows="1" ng-reflect-placeholder="Write a comment"></textarea>
            <span class="mat-input-placeholder-wrapper"><!----></span>
        </div><!---->
    </div><div class="mat-input-underline"><span class="mat-input-ripple"></span></div><div class="mat-input-subscript-wrapper"><!----><!----></div>
</div>
```

mat-input-underline has just 3 line css.

```
.mat-input-underline {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also `<input type="text" mdInput\>` not working too. I tried reinstall material but it did not work also. So I do not have a clue about why it is not styling. And this is not a duplicate question, it has no relationship with angular verison.

Comment: It is on beta-12 now so, it might be worthwhile ruling that out first if easy.

Comment: have you included theme ?

Comment: I have included the theme but it was the source of the problem.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677546/angular-4-3-4-breaks-mdinput-and-md-input-container?rq=1 this answer helped me.

Comment: btw, this is not duplicate. I just said it just helped me ffs.